# C++11 move semantics when return a local object

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I saw some similar questions but could not find a clear explanation for my problem. Here is the code (that can be found here: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/nBiik8pMkpKCD3Jv):

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
  public:
  explicit A(int a)         {std::cout << "Main constructor" << std::endl;}
  A(const A& a)             {std::cout << "Copy constructor" << std::endl;}
  A& operator =(const A& a) {std::cout << "Copy assignment" << std::endl; return *this;}
  A(A&& a)                  {std::cout << "Move constructor" << std::endl;}
  A& operator =(A&& a)      {std::cout << "Move assignemnt" << std::endl; return *this;}
};

A getA(bool b)        {std::cout << "In getA" << std::endl; A a(0); return b ? a : A(1);}
A getA_Move(bool b)   {std::cout << "In getA_Move" << std::endl; A a(0); return std::move(b ? a : A(1));}

int main(void) {
    std::cout << "\nA a0(getA(true))" << std::endl;
    A a0(getA(true));
    std::cout << "\nA a1(getA(false))" << std::endl;
    A a1(getA(false));    
    std::cout << "\nA a2(getA(true))" << std::endl;
    A a2(getA_Move(true));
    std::cout << "\nA a3(getA(false))" << std::endl;
    A a3(getA_Move(false));    
}
```

As far as I understood: The return of a function is an rvalue (because as opposite to an lvalue it has no name and thus cannot be re used).
Thus when creating an object which is taking the return value of a function as a parameter this parameter should be moved if it is moveable. However this is not what I can observe:

```
Start


A a0(getA(true))
Main constructor
In getA
Copy constructor  <- Why is not this a move ?

A a1(getA(false))
Main constructor
In getA
Main constructor

A a2(getA(true))
Main constructor
In getA_Move
Copy constructor <- I would have expected a move here as well
Move constructor

A a3(getA(false))
Main constructor
In getA_Move
Main constructor
Move constructor

0

Finish
```

Thanks @T.C. I modified the program to use a normal if and then the program works as expected. Result can be found here: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/6h0ODi1SHdUj4HvX

Comment: That copy happens in the evaluation of `?:`, not the subsequent return.

Comment: note: the optimal way to write the function would be `if ( b ) return a; else return A(0);`  , avoid the problem with conditional operator

Comment: Thanks @M.M, this is actually what the last link I provided shows as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Briefly, this is because `foo ? lvalue-of-X : rvalue-of-X` results in a temporary of type `X` initialized from the selected operand - a copy if the second is selected, and a move if the third is selected.

Then, that temporary is returned - first moved into the return value, then into the variable in `main`.

The "local variables are treated as rvalues in return" rule applies only when said local variable is being returned directly.

GCC's handling here is a little bugged - it elides the move from the third operand even with `-fno-elide-constructors`. With clang, you'll see [the triple move](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/tVqv3a167RNzQrwy) when the third operand is picked.

Answer (score 0):

this is due to [copy elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) compiler optimization. "*Copy elision is the only allowed form of optimization that can change the observable side-effects*"

Comment: Copy elision and RVO is not really regarded as optimization any more, they are now part of the language

Comment: @sp2danny Can you provide a reference? Judging by the link, copy elision is very much an optimization - the telling sentence being *Because some compilers do not perform copy elision in every situation where it is allowed (e.g., in debug mode), programs that rely on the side-effects of copy/move constructors and destructors are not portable.*